# How do I get a CSS sticky bar to pass floated divs?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I have a sticky bar (not a fixed bar) that I want to create. It starts at the bottom then as the user scrolls down, it sticks to the top. Its not exactly a sticky-footer, but similar. I want it to work like this website: http://gardenestudio.com.br/index.php

It won't pass any floated divs when I write the code in CSS. I know its the floats because when I remove the floats from .servlist and .textbox1, the sticky bar passes them without a problem. When I add them back in, it won't pass those Is it POSSIBLE to get a sticky bar to pass floated divs? Using ONLY CSS?

If so how? If not, I know everyone recommends javascript but I'd need a super super easy jquery, with simple explanations on how to implement it. I don't know javascript so most of the time when I copy and paste code it doesn't work, probably because its not explained how to implement for someone who knows just about zero javascript. Hence why I'd rather do it in CSS if possible.

```
    .navbar {
    margin-top:0%;
    background-color: #24265b;
    height:20%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 99999;

}

.servlist {
    height: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #24265b;

}

.textbox1 {
    height:50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #24265b;

}
```

Comment: Maybe this tutorial could help you along the way: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042